What is this general prohibition/slash symbol on my Xcode app
Any ideas as to why I have this slash symbol on Xcode?


What happens when you double-click on that icon? Does Xcode start or do you get an error message?

It starts up and asks what kind of project I want to start

Since most likely you are using the new macOS Sequoia, this means that the current version of Xcode is not compatible with OS version.
If you have installed Xcode via App Store, you can simply update to the latest version of Xcode which I believe currently is v16.
If you have installed Xcode manually, first delete this version and then go to: https://xcodereleases.com/ and install the latest stable version.

Thank you for your reply. I updated Xcode via the App Store immediately following updating to Sequoia and I still have this slash symbol. I never use the app launcher so I don't know how long it's been there.

While I don't know the exact cause of this; I've had "legacy software" that retains this icon even after it's updated but never started. So, click on it. The icon has never failed to update to be normal after the application boots once.
If the software is not compatible, you will find out why after clicking on it.

If Xcode launches without incident, and seems to work normally, then I suspect it's just a caching error. As said in other answers, Xcode generally needs to be updated for each new OS, so if there was a mismatch, that icon may have got stuck.

Just restart your os and it disappears.
